# IIS Express crashing in Web Matrix

Tags: webmatrix, iis-express

I'm having an issue with IIS Express (7.5) crashing whenever I launch a site in Web Matrix 2. The same sites launch fine from VS2010. The IIS icon appears in the tray, with the site listed as a running application, then disappears as soon as Chrome launches. Web Matrix serves the 'following site has stopped: xxxxxx' error.

I've uninstalled/reinstalled IIS Express and Web Matrix, have launched IIS from the command line, including error trace and it's all fine. Have also commented out the HttpLoggingModule key in the applicationhost.config file.

What else could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Running webmatrix as administrator solved this, so figure it must be a security/permissions setting.